# Laravel 5 on digitalocean: cannot connect to database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I have this in env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE={db_name}
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD={db_password}
```

I config/database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false, //true is default
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

That's how I got the password:

```
cat /root/.digitalocean_password
```

But I get

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` ....
```

I even cleared the password value in env file but ti doesn't work too. Any help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u try connecting via SSH on your database and try to do sudo mysql -uroot  -p command and enter your password?

Answer (score 0):

To backtrace your issue.  try to connect via SSH on  your  database server . then try  to  do this

```
$ sudo  mysql -uroot -p
$ password : ******** (enter your password here)
```

If you were able to connect, probably you shouldn't have any problem on  your app level.

second option is : try to use host `"localhost"` instead of `"127.0.0.1"`  as  your **root** username might only pointed to `@localhost` instead of `@127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I got:

I had to create another user rather than `root` and add all permissions to that new user which will sure have a new password. I used that username and password in `.env` file for database connection and it worked fine.